# Docker + nginx + PHP - nginx does not point to the root directory?

Tags: php, nginx, docker, docker-compose

I follow this [guide](http://geekyplatypus.com/dockerise-your-php-application-with-nginx-and-php7-fpm/) to run PHP on Docker, but nginx does **not** point to the root directory that I have set in site.conf.

docker-compose.yml:

```
nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
        - 8080:80
    volumes:
        - ./code:/code
        - ./site.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/site.conf
    links:
        - php
php:
    image: php:7-fpm
    volumes:
        - ./code:/code
```

site.conf:

```
server {
    index index.php index.html;
    server_name localhost;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    root /code;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass php:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }
}
```

code/index.php:

```
<?php
echo phpinfo();
```

On my terminal, I run:

```
docker-compose up
```

Result:

[image]

But it should be:

[image]

Any ideas why?

**EDIT:**

```
server {
    index index.php index.html;
    server_name docker.loc;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    root /code;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass php:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }
}
```

I get this error when I run `docker-compose up`:

```
nginx_1 | 172.17.0.1 - - [01/Jan/2017:20:35:17 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 571 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/55.0.2883.87 Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36"
nginx_1 | 2017/01/01 20:35:17 [error] 6#6: *5 directory index of "/code/" is forbidden, client: 172.17.0.1, server: docker.php, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "docker.php:8080"
```

Where is `docker.php` coming from??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have domain name conflict. Set `server_name docker.loc;` in site.conf. And then add `127.0.0.1 docker.loc` to /etc/hosts on your local machine. Then you can get access to dockerised application by `docker.loc:8080`

Or you can try resolve conflict. I think problem maybe in `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default`

Comment: thanks. But I now get a page of `403 Forbidden` when I browse the site at `docker.loc:8080`

Comment: should be work, I tested it. Show your configuration

Comment: which config file?

Comment: `site.conf` and check `code` folder, maybe it  not exists `index.php`

Comment: that folder does exist. i have updated my question. have a look. thanks.

Comment: looks like you write `docker.php` in /etc/hosts and try get access by this name

Comment: it works now. i made a mistake by changing `./code:/code` to `.:/code`.

Comment: that is folder sharing `path_on_host:path_on_container`